# Assist with re Module

Tags: python

I need to extract all those strings between the patterns nr: or /nr:. Can anyone please help me?

The string is

```
nr:Organization/nr:Customer/nr:Agreement/nr:date/nr:coverage/nr:Premium/nr:Option/nr:OptionID
```

Output I am expecting is

```
Organization, Customer, Agreement,...OptionID
```

Comment: What have you tried? can you show your code and explain what difficulties you are having?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without using the "re" module, it looks like this would work:

```
test_string = 'nr:Organization/nr:Customer/nr:Agreement/nr:date/nr:coverage/nr:Premium/nr:Option/nr:OptionID'
columns = [f[3:] for f in test_string.split('/')]
print(columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `re` module, `split` the string and filter out matches whose lengths are 0:

```
import re

test_string = "nr:Organization/nr:Customer/nr:Agreement/nr:date/nr:coverage/nr:Premium/nr:Option/nr:OptionID"

columns = [x for x in re.split("/{0,1}nr:",test_string) if len(x) > 0]

print(columns)

['Organization', 'Customer', 'Agreement', 'date', 'coverage', 'Premium', 'Option', 'OptionID']
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with regular expression and split:

```
import re

string = 'nr:Organization/nr:Customer/nr:Agreement/nr:date/nr:coverage/nr:Premium/nr:Option/nr:OptionID'

x = filter(None, re.split('/*nr:', string))
print x
```

The regular expression looks for `nr:` preceded (or not) by a '/'. Since the `re.split` function would leave some empty elements, applying a `filter` to it, will give you the desired output.

Also see it in action here: https://eval.in/656744